# CSS Arrow vertically-centered on the right side of a div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

As the title says, I am trying to center vertically a CSS triangle/arrow onto the right side of a div, and of course, I am looking to do this using a pure CSS solution.

I would have included pictures, but because of my low-rep, I can't.

Note: My current code isn't working properly and is not cross-browser compatible (i.e. Chrome puts the arrow on the top right~ but on Firefox, it gets squished down outside the bounds)

**My code**

*HTML*:

```
<div class="main-panel">
    <nav class="left-panel">
        <ul class="page-nav">
            <li class="page-tab active"><a class="page-nav-link">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Page 1</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Page 2</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Page 3</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abc</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abcdef</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abcdefghi</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abcdefghijkl</a></li>
            <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Very long element abcdefghijklmno</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="right-panel">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pellentesque nisl vitae nulla dignissim, at rutrum nunc interdum. Mauris et facilisis orci. Phasellus ac libero id nisl malesuada ultricies. Aenean vitae cursus velit. Nulla sit amet leo eu enim scelerisque volutpat. Vivamus gravida felis et pulvinar mollis. Sed bibendum consectetur nisi, sit amet tincidunt enim interdum a. Duis sed gravida felis. Fusce mauris est, bibendum a neque et, fringilla placerat magna. Vestibulum pellentesque massa quis bibendum dapibus. Praesent pharetra ipsum id libero dapibus rutrum. Quisque accumsan dictum lacinia.
            Mauris ut mi nec orci accumsan consequat. Donec blandit augue eget nulla fermentum, quis porttitor lacus feugiat. Proin vehicula dolor id lorem egestas elementum. Nullam vitae rutrum tortor. Proin varius adipiscing nibh. Vivamus ultrices nibh nec varius bibendum. Integer quis nisi sed metus adipiscing sagittis. Curabitur congue, nisi nec pretium suscipit, mi leo posuere dui, pellentesque dapibus ligula urna a ligula. Quisque mauris nisl, interdum eu est in, elementum cursus arcu. Sed suscipit vel erat vitae viverra. Mauris neque ipsum, bibendum eget hendrerit ac, vulputate in eros. Ut tincidunt, urna ac auctor porttitor, mauris purus varius erat, ut pellentesque urna turpis non nibh. Aenean sed neque a velit tristique tristique.
            Praesent id cursus libero. Vestibulum pulvinar feugiat neque pretium suscipit. Nam vitae magna eget elit aliquam accumsan. Duis et eleifend enim. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec nunc est, commodo quis pretium vitae, lacinia ac lectus. Cras mi tellus, suscipit non leo eget, auctor feugiat mauris. Praesent vitae vehicula ipsum, nec ultrices arcu. Proin mollis leo sit amet erat scelerisque feugiat. Nullam eget varius ante. Praesent a laoreet libero.
            Suspendisse ut eros et odio rhoncus malesuada. Integer laoreet, leo at fringilla volutpat, augue lorem tincidunt augue, sit amet feugiat erat neque in est. Phasellus imperdiet, nisi vel faucibus auctor, sapien orci mollis est, tincidunt vehicula nisi nunc sit amet purus. Sed cursus ipsum nisi, id elementum leo feugiat in. Phasellus vitae arcu ac ligula pellentesque malesuada. Maecenas vulputate nunc et consequat pellentesque. Nulla semper quam a orci eleifend, vel gravida est euismod. Nam fermentum, nisi ullamcorper congue convallis, turpis purus lacinia ligula, ac posuere urna est non felis. Cras lobortis ligula neque, vel fermentum magna facilisis sit amet. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
            Quisque a quam nec sem vestibulum dapibus quis non lacus. Integer eget ligula eu turpis pretium iaculis. Cras gravida ligula in mauris bibendum placerat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Proin ac tristique risus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque diam nisi, sodales vel nisi a, sollicitudin commodo ipsum. Fusce elementum nisi ac semper dignissim. Etiam nec felis dapibus lacus faucibus vehicula eget eu odio. Sed id risus tellus. Curabitur in luctus orci.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.main-panel {
    min-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: 700px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    background: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.4);
}

.left-panel {
    border-width: 2px 0 0 0 0;
    background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4); /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4), rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4)); /* For Chrome and Safari */
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4), rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4)); /*     For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4), rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4)); /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4), rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4)); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
    background:         linear-gradient(to center bottom, rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4), rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.4)); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 7px white inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 7px white inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px white inset;

    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 180px;
    max-width: 280px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 7px;
}

.right-panel {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
}

.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: solid 1px rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab.active {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.6) inset;
    background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4); /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4), rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.4)); /* For Chrome and Safari */
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4), rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.4)); /*   For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4), rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.4)); /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4), rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.4)); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
    background:         linear-gradient(to center bottom, rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.4), rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.4)); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
}

.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab.active:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;

    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 7px solid white;
    margin-right: -5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.6) inset;
}
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/LvG2C/

Comment: What is the arrow that you speak of? I don't see anyting in the jsfiddle

Comment: @ProfileTwist It's probably due to the browser you are using, may I ask which one? Also, see those pictures: Chrome (Somewhat working, but not vertically-centered): http://d.pr/i/4mzU, Firefox (Not working correctly): http://d.pr/i/YLom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab {
    position: relative;
}

.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab.active:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 7px 7px 0;
    border-color: transparent #ffffff transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -7px;
    content: "";
}
```

height triangle 14px, for vertical alignment to do it: 14/2 = 7, for this margin-top: -7px;

[***Example***](http://jsfiddle.net/ShootingStar/VXUCJ/1/)

By the way, the [***generator triangles***](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Comment: Works flawlessly. Also, thanks for the generator, it might come in handy ;)

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative solution keeping float in the run* 
Using line-height value + font-size to set size of arrow and margin.
http://jsfiddle.net/LvG2C/3/

**edit:** what follows is **not compatible with text-ellipsis** if you turn **`<a>`** as one inline-block.

you use float. it is not compatible with vertical-align.

You can set  as inline-box and the arrow too to vertical-align them mutually.
give a width to a to push arrow all the way : 
http://jsfiddle.net/LvG2C/1/

```
.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab.active:after {
    content:" ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid white;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
.left-panel > .page-nav > .page-tab:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.6) inset;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:-3px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this seems to break the text-overflow attribute. See the comparison: http://d.pr/i/TQ5B (yours) vs http://d.pr/i/mgay

Comment: did not see that, but i noticed that display:flex did not work in my firefox. I'll check again, thank you for showing me :)

Comment: No problem. Also, what do you mean by "did not work"? Are you, perhaps, running an old version of Firefox?

Comment: no it's update, but content goes under menu and takes 100% of width (win7).Actually, text-ellipsis still not showing up in either my chrome or Firefox. change my mind and used em to size and reposition arrow from: line-height:25px and font-size:11px; http://jsfiddle.net/LvG2C/2/

Comment: edit, text-ellipsis works, i just add to reach max-width before see it in action

Comment: Hmm that's weird.. probably due to a bug with the flex display. About your jsfiddle, it does not seem to work the same way as it does for you: http://d.pr/i/b1TG. Are you perhaps running Firefox for OSX?

Comment: it works in FF this way ,so i should reinstall it ,and might get rid of some plugins. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to set a class on the elements that you wish to have an arrow on the left side centered vertically.  In the class would look something like:

```
.left-arrow {
    background: url('/images/arrow.png') 0% 50% no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px; // Number of pixels you need to offset the content to make the content come after the arrow the way you want it to.
}
```

This would mean that any element with a class="left-arrow" attribute would have an arrow centered vertically on the left side.  Then the nav code would look like:

```
<nav class="left-panel">
    <ul class="page-nav">
        <li class="page-tab active"><a class="page-nav-link">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Page 1</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Page 3</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link left-arrow">Somewhat long</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abc</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abcdef</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abcdefghi</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Somewhat long abcdefghijkl</a></li>
        <li class="page-tab"><a class="page-nav-link">Very long element abcdefghijklmno</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah, this might be a good alternative for non-CSS3-capable browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Nice use of CSS3 there. If your client is okay with you using cSS3 then your method suffices (if it isn't the best option out there). However, I work for clients that require the use of legacy browsers and as a matter of fact my work still actively uses IE7/8.

This is the approach I would employ for a simple arrow styling solution. It is simple, robust, and compatible with IE5+. IN addition, this method will work beautifully on mobile devices and tablet browsers. (Know your customers/client needs and decide if you want to fall back on this method).

1. Create the arrow in photoshop and save it as a .png . The file should only be 50bytes or something ridiculously small. (5px X 10px).
2. Create the gradient in photoshop as well. It should be (1px wide) and the height should match be exactly two times that of an li element. Create a normal / hover state on the image. So the first y pixels should be normal gradient and the next y pixels should be hover over gradient. We will use css to change the positioning of the background. NO reason to create 2 gradient images.
3. Deploy CSS2.

   li {
   background: url(gradient.png) repeat-x;
   height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #000;
      font-size: 14px;
   }
   li:hover {
      background-position: 0 -30px;
   }
   li a {
      background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat 100% center;
   }

This should get you started. And show you an alternative approach.

#### SO is bugging out and can't get the code to code block to format

Comment: Actually, it is not for a client, exclusively for myself :P. And I am not so sure where this is going right now.. but still, I'll sure be trying to make my website more cross-browser compatible in the future.